# ValueError: Extra data: Importing multiple JSON frame from JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, file

I am trying to import multiple JSON frames stored in JSON file to python.
My code is:

```
import json
import array

with open("J1.json") as J:
    j_Data = json.load(J)
    print j_Data
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhi/Desktop/CSS HTML/Python Mongo/JSONtoMongoDB.py", line 9, in <module>
    j_Data = json.load(J)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 1113 - line 1 column 2225 (char 1112 - 2224)
```

My JSON file data is as follows:

Comment: I think you may have had an error when copying your JSON data.

Comment: It is working fine with one JSON frame but with multiple frame I am receiving error.

Comment: please upload your JSON file

Comment: {"yphthd": "123.32"}{"yphthd": "123.32"}

Comment: If I take  
{"yphthd": "123.32"} only it is working fine but with two JSON objects it is creating problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make array of your JSON frames in JSON file:

```
[{"yphthd": "123.32"} , {"yphthd": "123.32"}, ... {"yphthd": "123.32"}]
```

and then load it:

```
with open("J1.json") as J:
    j_Data = json.load(J)
    print j_Data
```